# python paramiko Issue while closing the connection

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I have just been trying ssh connection with `paramiko`.
Everything looks fine, but in the final step, when calling the `close()` method to disconnect the client.

Here is my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import paramiko
import os

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
private_key = os.path.expanduser('~/.ssh/id_dsa')
mkey = paramiko.DSSKey.from_private_key_file(private_key,password='JacquiKoala')
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('monitor', username='probert', pkey = mkey)
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('whoami')
print stdout.readlines()
ssh.close
```

The shell just hangs, I can type stuff, without any result, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> don't stop the script nor the connection. I have no other way except closing the shell window which is kind of dirty.

I am running Ubuntu 10.10 with `python 2.6.6` and `paramiko-1.7.4` compiled from sources.

I really don't know what happens; the `close()` method is correctly executed as a print "blah" after is executed as well, no error message, and still connected without an appropriate way to stop it.

Thanks for helping me :)

Cheers;

Philippe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: You are not calling the function. Do so with `ssh.close()` instead of `ssh.close`

`ssh.close` is a reference to that function. It tells you about the function, it does not call the function. Here is an example:

```
def a():
    return 6

a
> <function a at 0x108f71aa0>
a()
> 6
```