# Running database script with Paramiko fails with exit code

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

The output file is created before the database results are available.

Passing a simple os command works fine:

```
# command = "whoami > result.txt"
```

works fine. I would get my user name when I open the result.txt file. The problem is waiting for the database to return the result. It comes out empty even though there is data returned from the actual query

```py
import paramiko


def get_report(command):
    # reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193886/python-paramiko-issue-while-closing-the-connection.
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    client.connect('server123', username='username', password='password')

    stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(command)
    exit_status = stdout.channel.recv_exit_status()

    if exit_status == 0:
        print("File processed")
    else:
        print("Error", exit_status)
    client.close()

command = "sql_query.script > result.txt"
get_report(command=command)
```

I expect to received a data set of first_name, last_name, and location but instead I get Error 108.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a command does not work, when executed using Paramiko, debug it by reading its error output.

Use `stderr.readlines()` for that.

---

If the same command works in regular shell, but not in Paramiko, the problem is usually related to a different environment used by the SSH "exec" channel, which is used by [`SSHClient.exec_command`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.exec_command). See:

- [Some Unix commands fail with "<command> not found", when executed using Python Paramiko exec_command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55419330/850848)
- [Environment variable differences when using Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31964108/850848)